# boost Unit test doesn't fail

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I am learning about boost unit tests, I found out, happily, that it can detect memory leaks, so I am testing it. I created the following horrible method:

```
int ForTest::Compare(const ForTest item)
{
    ForTest* existing_item = this;
    char* x=new char[1024];
    m_name = std::string(x);
    if (existing_item->m_count * existing_item->m_price == item.m_count * item.m_price) return 0;
    if (existing_item->m_count * existing_item->m_price > item.m_count * item.m_price) return 1;    
    return -1;
}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( a_test_case)
{
    BOOST_TEST_CHECKPOINT("weird...");

    ForTest alpha("Pen", 4, 4.3);
    ForTest beta;

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(alpha.Compare(beta), 1);  
}
```

I am obviously creating 2 memory leaks here. Why doesn't the tester care ? My test passes with flying colors.

I don't want to have to modify actual code, as I saw here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/test/example/exec_mon_example.cpp

Why am I not getting an error ?

Comment: Which platform are you running on?  The Boost Execution Monitor memory leak detection only works on some platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about boost but to get debug heap manager of Visual Studio to work you have to write something like that:

```
#include <crtdbg.h>

#ifdef _DEBUG
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#define new new( _NORMAL_BLOCK, THIS_FILE, __LINE__ )
#endif

int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF | _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG ) );
    new int(2036427631); // deliberate leak
}
```

Since it leaks the output of the DEBUG version will look something like that:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
d:\fun\try\try.cpp(11) : {66} normal block at 0x00345C40, 4 bytes long.
 Data: <okay> 6F 6B 61 79 
Object dump complete.
The program '[3216] try.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Probably boost uses very same thing to detect the memory leaks.

The RELEASE version does not detect memory leaks because the "debug heap manager" of Visual Studio does not work in RELEASE version. What you think why they named it as "debug heap manager"?

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question about the fact that the tests don't work in Release. Still, I keep trying to make a replica of the Debug configuration, unsuccessfully. I suppose I can mark your answer as the solution, and ask a separate question as to why/how that doesn't work, because I will not be able to set up tests any other way - the Debug has to be able to run actual executable code.

Comment: @Michaela Try to produce a bare minimum example unit test that does not work for you. Something that compiles. It is very likely that in the process you find the solution.

Comment: All my other unit tests work. (either to pass or fail). They all compile. They give correct expected results. The only thing that doesn't work is creating a Debug configuration, that will produce a memory leak. Please see example above. That test should not pass. It does.

Comment: @Michaela By http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/test/doc/html/execution-monitor/user-guide.html you just need to run it with `--detect_memory_leak=yes`. It does not say it should be debug version but by my experience it should. If that still does not work for you then ask in boost discussion groups http://www.boost.org/community/groups.html Perhaps someone from there can help you further.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself clearly. In DEBUG, the test fails. But I am unable to create a DEBUG configuration. So, I did ask a separate question about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865484/visual-studio-new-debug-configuration#comment17418467_12865484 I have not been able to get an answer yet, and I am still trying to figure it out. That is not a boost or unit testing question though, it is really a Visual Studio issue. Thank you.