# Visual Studio New Debug Configuration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, configuration, configurationmanager

I am trying to configure Visual Studio 2010, to add a Debug configuration.

Configuration Manager->either by starting in the active solution configuration:, or Project, added New, created a New configuration, copied from Debug... (if solution, either created new configuration, or just used Debug and added new project configuration)...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx

Build -> errors that suggest a mix of Debug and Release:

defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library -> easy to fix

mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' -> don't know how to fix.

I tried to manually change the project file... But I don't know how to fix this. [image: resultant configuration ?]

What is more, I can't just fix this specific instance - there will be lots and lots of situations where this situation will happen again, so, what am I doing wrong ?

Note: I need a DEBUG configuration in order to be able to do unit testing (c++), and be able to separate building executables from unit tests.

Comment: Begin with menu _Build->Configuration Manager_, from there, use the pulldown under _Active solution configuration_, choose _<New...>_. In the dialog use the pulldown under _Copy settings from:_, and choose _Debug_. Add a new name in the text field, click _OK_.

Comment: I did that. The result: the above build errors. I have just recreated a solution from scratch, right now, with exactly the same results.

Comment: `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=0` seems like a Release value, did you try changing it to `2`?

Comment: That is exactly the question, I copied the DEBUG structure yet I ended up with some combination of DEBUG and RELEASE !!!!! How can I change it ? The only thing I can do is remove the "Inherit from parent or project defaults", then add all those values in by hand. That can't be the "templated" solution though.

Comment: If you add _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 to the top window, does it work?  I think it should be possible to 'override' values provided by the parent template like this, but I haven't tinkered with VS in a while.  Another solution would be to split your templates up for finer granularity, e.g., have a Common, Debug, and Release template, where your current template would be the Common one, but then you move the _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL and other such defines into the Debug and Release templates with proper settings.  The Debug, Release would inherit from Common, i.e., a template tree.

Comment: See above: I had to uncheck the "inherit from project defaults" to be able to change it, otherwise I still had error, even when adding additional ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL. And I am not trying to fix a sample project, I redid it several times with the same effect. I am trying to add a copy of the DEBUG configuration, and have it work, without having to spend another half an hour changing and fixing other properties - for up to a hundred other projects. If this demo project doesn't work, than I may as well give up on the whole idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can set the configuration options in a property sheet, where I can add things like

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'DebugCopy'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL=2;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

(as well as any other options I require that may not be set by default).

It is a way to override some global settings that have been imposed on all projects I am using, which have caused the bug I had (mostly because I wasn't aware of those settings).

Comment: Having problems to set it on existing project and found C/C++ / Code Generation / Runtime Library / Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd) works, but /MD not on small test project.